# Dockerizing Python Gets Unsatisfied Dependency Exception

Tags: python, docker, fastapi

This running without problem:

`pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt`

But when run it inside Dockerfile it gets that err:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cloud-init==20.2 (from versions: none)`

This is Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/server
WORKDIR /user/src/app/server

COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/server

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /usr/src/app/server/requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app/server

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a version of cloud-init on pypi, so you might want to install it through apt instead? `RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get install -y cloud-init`

Comment: can you provide your requirements.txt so we can replicate the issue?

Comment: I solved the problem. Actually it was my mistake. I freeze all installed modules on the system.